# Why Beta Distribution for Credit Migration

Tags: credit-ratings

When modelling credit migration probabilities (e.g. AAA to AA), research has indicated the use of the Beta Distribution simply because it fits empirical data. My question is;

What are some other pros and what are some cons of modelling using this distribution? Are there any other distributions that could possibly be used?

Answer (score 1):

I would think it is because

- it can be bound between 2 points
- it can assume wide range shapes
- It fits the data empirically (as you said)

On a related note 
Sometime back I read a [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=958150) which might give you more formal reason. It is for estimating and simulating recovery rates . I havnt used it to model credit migration probabilities . But I think one can extend the structural model mentioned in paper and explain why probabilities can me modelling similarly.